# Is a minimal surface $S$ that is bounded by an analytic closed curve $C$, analytic?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $C$ be an analytic closed curve (in the form of an unknot) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $S$ be a minimal surface (a disk) bound by $C$. Is $S$ always analytic? Can you point out some references?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the surface is analytic (has an analytic parametrization without branch points inside) but it may not be embedded. (Thurston had a counterexample of unknotted
curve which does not bound an embedded minimal disk).
There is a survey with references in the beginning of this article:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938382900210